# Is there a word that describes when too much audio is being play simultaneously?

Tags: audio, sound, terminology, sound-effects

In Unity, before I managed sounds properly, if too many accumulated at the same it would become this loud drowned out mega sound (like the speakers got blown out). With proper audio management this is never an issue, but it's funny how many times I see this problem come up in professional level games (notably Demon's Souls and Dark Souls when too many collisions happen with breakable boxes triggering too many sounds to happen at once).

Is there a word that describes that drowned out mega sound that happens when too many sounds are being played at once? Also, what's the process that's happening on the audio technical side when this sound is played, meaning are the sounds just being shoved into one mixer or something?

Comment: I think this is on-topic for Game Development, but you might find there's a higher concentration of experts in audio terminology at the [Sound Design StackExchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com), so asking there instead might get you better answers, faster.

Answer (score 1):

The word I believe you are searching for is cacophony.

ca·coph·o·ny

/kəˈkäfənē/

noun: cacophony; plural noun: cacophonies

a harsh, discordant mixture of sounds.

"a cacophony of deafening alarm bells"

synonyms:   din, racket, noise, clamor, discord, dissonance, discordance, uproar
"despite the cacophony, Rita slept on"